# Invalid syntax in Python's for statement

Tags: python, for-loop, python-2.6

I am trying to run the code below, and when I run `python tfidf.py` (Python 2.6.9) I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error in the line below, pointing to the for statement. What am I doing wrong?

```
def produceVector(blob, bloblist):
    ##### SYNTAXERROR: invalid syntax in the "for" in the line below #####
    scores = {word: tfidf(word, blob, bloblist) for word in blob.words}
    return scores

def tf(word, blob):
    return blob.words.count(word) / len(blob.words)

def n_containing(word, bloblist):
    return sum(1 for blob in bloblist if word in blob)

def idf(word, bloblist):
    return math.log(len(bloblist) / (1 + n_containing(word, bloblist)))

def tfidf(word, blob, bloblist):
    return tf(word, blob) * idf(word, bloblist)
```

Comment: I just cut the first four lines of what you posted out of Stackoverflow and into the Python interpreter (Idle) and got no errors. Possibly, you had an invisible control character accidentally inserted in your original which Stackoverflow sanitized. Try cut/pasting it back, does it then pass syntax checking?

Comment: Dict comprehensions not available in Python 2.6

Comment: Ah. I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a for statement, that's a dict comprehension. Which was only introduced in 2.7. Generate an iterable of 2-tuples instead and pass it to the `dict()` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [3, 2, 1, 0]
d = {i: a[i] for i in a}        # python > 2.6
e = dict((i, a[i]) for i in a)  # python <= 2.6 
print e == d
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.